# Drop certain columns in dataframe - ignore items not in index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a few hundred dataframes that are broadly similar, but contain some differences. I would like to filter each dataframe to only contain columns where the column name exists in a predefined list. See below:

```
import pandas as pd

col_list = ['red','green','blue','yellow','orange']

my_data = {'red':[1,2,3,5,6], 'purple':[3,5,1,6,2], 'orange':[2,6,5,7,3]}
my_df = pd.DataFrame(my_data)    

my_subdf = my_df[col_list]
```

The problem I am having is that I get a KeyError (*"['yellow', 'green', 'blue'] not in index*) unless every column is represented in the original dataframe, which I cannot guarantee.

How can I get around this so that I ignore the index and achieve something along the lines of the following (psuedo-code):

```
if column in my_df
    column.append(my_subdf)

else:
    ignore/continue
```

Comment: `my_subdf = my_df[ [c for c in my_df.columns if c in col_list]]`?

Comment: Or `my_df[np.intersect1d(my_df.columns, col_list)]`.

Comment: The first one did the trick. Simpler than I thought it was going to be. - If you put it forward as an answer and I can mark it as correct. Thanks.

Comment: @Quang Hoang, out of curiosity, why is the first solution in double-brackets? Admittedly it works with them, and not without them, but given that there is nothing that exists outside of the inner bracket but inside the outside bracket I'm unclear why it is needed.

Comment: `[c for c in my_df.columns if c in col_list]` returns a list of column names. Then you use `my_df[ some_list ]` to extract the columns by names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have all the columns from `col_list`, you can use `reindex`:

```
my_subdf = my_df.reindex(columns=col_list)
```

gives:

```
   red  green  blue  yellow  orange
0    1    NaN   NaN     NaN       2
1    2    NaN   NaN     NaN       6
2    3    NaN   NaN     NaN       5
3    5    NaN   NaN     NaN       7
4    6    NaN   NaN     NaN       3
```

If you only want the intersection, you could do

```
my_subdf = my_df.reindex(columns=[col for col in my_df.columns if col in set(col_list)])
```

to get:

```
   red  orange
0    1       2
1    2       6
2    3       5
3    5       7
4    6       3
```